# PHP for each drop down selected

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, selected

I got this piece of code here...

```
<form action="InvoiceNotice.php?action=invoicenotice" method="post">
<label for="fordays">Select Day</label>
<select name="daySelected" id="daySelected">
<option value="0">Today</option>
<?php
$array = array_combine(range(1,$InvoiceDaysArray['days']), range(1,$InvoiceDaysArray['days']));
foreach($array as $row => $value){
    $selected = '';
    $daySelected = 0;
    if($daySelected == $row){
    $selected = 'SELECTED';
    }
    echo "<option selected='" . $selected . "' value='" . $row . "'>" . $value . " days ago</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

My issue is with the `$selected` the $daysSelected variable comes from what has been selected. What I am trying to do is when a user selects an option, that option is now selected in the dropdown and the page returns, after the client hits submit.

Does any one know what I am talking about?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
foreach($array as $row => $value){
    $selected = '';
    if($_POST['daySelected'] == $row){
        $selected = ' selected="selected"';
    }
    echo "<option" . $selected . " value='" . $row . "'>" . $value . " days ago</option>";
}
```

Although you probably only need `selected` instead of `selected="selected"`.

Answer (score 1):

I see some problems in your code: 
first you are setting `$daySelected = 0;` and then try compare with variable from database, day 0 is not in your foreach loop try this

```
    <form action="InvoiceNotice.php?action=invoicenotice" method="post">
<label for="fordays">Select Day</label>
<select name="daySelected" id="daySelected">
<option value="0">Today</option>
<?php
$array = array_combine(range(1,$InvoiceDaysArray['days']), range(1,$InvoiceDaysArray['days']));
foreach($array as $row => $value){
    $selected = '';
    $daySelected = $_POST['daySelected'];
    if($daySelected == $row){
    $selected = "selected=SELECTED";
    }else {$selected='';}
    echo "<option '" . $selected . "' value='" . $row . "'>" . $value . " days ago</option>";
}
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
</form>
```